# Identifying an entity in article

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, named-entity-recognition

I am working with Python on a Data Science related task. What I need to do is - I have extracted some news articles and now I want to selectively pick only those news articles belonging to a specific person and determine if the person mentioned in the article is the same person I am interested in.

Let's say a person can be identified by either his name or certain attributes that describes that person, for example, a person with name "X" is a political figure. When an article about that person is published, we 'know' that it is referring to that person only by reading the context of the article. By 'context' I mean if the article contains any (or a combination of following ):

- That person's name
- The name of his political party
- Names of other people closely associated with him mentioned in the article
- Other attributes that describe that person

Because names are common, I want to determine what is the probability (how much probability) that a given article speaks about that person "X" only and not any other person having the same name as "X".

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html#named-entity-recognition

Comment: @bebop , This won't solve my problem as I am not trying to identify all textual mentions of the named entities. I want to determine the probability that person "X" mentioned in a given article is the same person I am looking for.

Comment: I can think of a solution involving supervised learning, ie classification between "This is the guy" and "This is not the guy". How many articles do you have with the person's name? Are they all about that person, or are some article about other people with the same name?

Comment: @HugoMailhot, I believe you are pointing in right direction to some extent. Lets say I have large number of articles and of course all of them are not about that person 'X'. Assume that 'X' is a very common name so chances are that there are some articles about other people with the same name. Thanks.

Comment: Hahaha, this is starting to sound like an interview question! I'll give it some thought and tell you what I come up with. I think it is a very interesting challenge. In mt view, he most powerful solution will necessitate a training set where people manually tagged whether each article really is about the particular person. A less labor-intensive solution would involve clustering the articles without tagging them, then analysis the clusters and tagging the clusters instead of the individual articles. This is less effort only if you have a LOT of articles, though, as the process is more complex.

Comment: @HugoMailhot, sounds like what you are suggesting is actually classification (using a classifier)?

Answer (score 3):

Alright so this is my best shot.

**Initial assumptions**

First, we assume that you have articles that already contain mentions of people, and these mentions are either **a)** mentions of the particular person you are looking for or **b)** mentions of other people sharing the same name.

I think to disambiguate each mention (as you would do in Entity Linking) is overkill, as you also assume that the articles are either about the person or not. So we'll say that any articles that contains at least one mention of the person is an article about the person.

**General solution: Text classification**

You have to develop a classification algorithm that extracts features from an article and feeds those features to a model you obtained through supervised learning. The model will output one of two answers, for example True or False. This necessitates a training set. For evaluation purposes (knowing that your solution works), you will also need a testing set.

So the first step will be to tag these training and testing sets using one of two tags each time ("True" and "False" or whatever). You have to assign these tags manually, by examining the articles yourself.

**What features to use**

@eldams mentions using contextual clues. In my (attempt at a) solution, the article is the context, so basically you have to ask yourself what might give away that the article is about the person in particular. At this point you can either choose the features yourself or let a more complex model find specific features in a more general feature category.

Two examples, assuming we are looking for articles about Justin Trudeau, the newly elected Canadian Prime Minister, as opposed to anyone else who is also named Justin Trudeau.

**A) Choosing features yourself**

With a bit of research, you will learn that Justin Trudeau leads the Liberal Party of Canada, so some good features would be to check whether or not the article contains these strings:

> Liberal Party of Canada, Parti Libéral du Canada, LPC, PLC, Liberals,
>   Libéraux, Jean Chrétien, Paul Martin, etc

Since Trudeau is a politician, looking for these might be a good idea:

> politics, politician, law, reform, parliament, house of commons, etc

You might want to gather information about his personal life, close collaborators, name of wife and kids, and so on, and add these as well.

**B) Letting the learning algorithm do the work**

Your other option would be to train an n-gram model using every n-gram there are in the training set (eg use all unigrams and bigrams). This results in a more complex model than can be more robust, as well as heavier to train and use.

**Software resources**

Whatever you choose to do, if you need to train a classifier, you should use [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/). Its [SVM](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html) classifier would be the most popular choice. [Naive Bayes](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html) is the more classic approach to document classification.

Comment: Nice solution! Indeed scikit-learn is a very convenient software and would undeniably achieve the machine-learning part. About features, usually, approaches compare the context of the mention (sentence, paragraph, article) to texts describing references (e.g. Wikipedia articles).

Comment: @HugoMailhot, I think you have hit the nail on the head. IMO a mix of both your approaches (A) and (B) above to construct features should deliver more  accurate results, i.e. a set of hand-picked words (by researching about that entity on Wikipedia for example) mixed with n-grams. I have to try to see what works best but overall it does seem to be pointing in right direction. Do you have any specific reason to recommend scikit-learn over NLTK ?

Comment: Also, I wanted to obtain a score so I believe that the "accuracy" figure I obtain in the classifier, for example  'nltk.classify.util.accuracy' can give me an accuracy score ? Thanks!

Comment: @AshutoshUpadhyay scikit-learn is widely used, well optimized and actively developed, plus knowing how to play with it will open up other machine learning application opportunities. Really you could probably do it with NLTK alone, but my advice is to familiarize yourself with the best ML module for Python. As for the accuracy, you will have to read documentation and test it yourself. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This task is usually known as **Entity Linking**. If you are working on popular entities, e.g. those that have an article in Wikipedia, then you may have a look at [DBpedia Spotlight](http://dbpedia-spotlight.github.io/demo/) or [BabelNet](http://babelnet.org/) that address this issue.

If you'd like to implement your own linker, than you may have a look at [related articles](http://blog.semantic-web.at/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/p1_mendes.pdf). In most cases, a named entity linker detects **mentions** (person names in your case), then a **disambiguation** step is required, which computes probabilities for available references (and NIL as a mention may not have a reference available), for any specific mention in text, and by using contextual clues (e.g. words of sentence, paragraph or whole article containing the mention).

Comment: Thanks for naming the problem!